# How to access variable inside a loop from outside the loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, variables, if-statement

I have tried putting variable inside loop and outside loop so other functions could use the variable but still get error. Using menu 1 I create a list. Then I want to be able to menu 4 to print list and average. I have it to do it all on menu 1 just to see that it works. but need to break it down. 1) list and 4) display.

```
bool exit = false;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create age list");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Add age to list");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Remove age from list");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Display ages and average");
            Console.WriteLine("5. exit");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            List<int> ages = new List<int>();
            int totalAges = 0;
            int age;

            if (input == "1")
            {

                //List<int> ages = new List<int>();
                //int totalAges = 0;

                //User Input
                Console.WriteLine("How many ages do you want to enter? ");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                //While loop for TryParse
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalAges))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                while (ages.Count != totalAges)
                {
                    // Read grade
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Grade: ");
                    //int age;

                    while (!int.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out age))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid age.");
                    }

                    ages.Add(age);
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < ages.Count(); index++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Age { ages[index] }");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    totalAges = ages.Sum();
                }

                double avg = 0.0;
                avg = totalAges / (ages.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine($"The average age was { avg}");


            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
                exit = true;
            }
            else if (input == "3")
            {
                exit = true;
            }
            else if (input == "4")
            {

                for (int index = 0; index < ages.Count(); index++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Age { ages[index] }");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    totalAges = ages.Sum();
                }

                double avg = 0.0;
                avg = totalAges / (ages.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine($"The average age was { avg}");
            }
            else if (input == "5")
            {
                exit = true;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How hard is it to type 1 or 2? Try again!");
            }
        } while (exit == false);
```

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]

Comment: Once I moved variables outside the loop, I get the values of zero which gives me error of divide by zero. I need the values of variables after 1 menu is ran.

Comment: looks like every iteration of the loop resets the age list, so when you add them in opt 1, it resets and count becomes 0 in opt 4

Comment: _ages_ should be declared and initialized before entering the loop otherwise it will be recreated at each loop loosing the previous inputs. Of coure before doing any operation on the _ages_ variable you should check if you could use it safely. For example in condition "4" you should check _if (ages.Count == 0) ... error..._

Comment: If I move variables inside 1 menu loop then in 4 menu I get error not local variable. I need to learn how to pass variable results outside loop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: remove it from loop and keep it as class property. Make it public if you have too

Comment: Steve, ages is my list name and is outside the loop. It's at the top. I that right? very new at this.

Comment: No it is inside the loop. It is declared and initialized after the _do_ that marks the loop start

Comment: Move List<int> ages = new List<int>(); just BEFORE do {

Comment: There is also another minor error. The _totalAges = ages.Sum();_ should be done outside the for..loop that display the single values. You are repeating the same invariant operation for every age inserted. Makes no sense

Comment: That seems to work, I moved it just Before do. Thanks now to work on other parts of the menu.

Comment: thanks Steve I did that before on another program had it inside my loop, which was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think in this case it would make more sense not to declare the variables you are trying to access in the method and instead in the class. You can instantiate it each time in the method if you wish to have it essentially reset every time you call the method. What I would also do is instead break up the if statements into their own methods. This would allow you to have a more OOP structured code.